# Получение концевых значений слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, слайдер

Есть код слайдера

```html
<div class="PriceSlider">
  <div class="PriceSlider__header">Цена, ₽</div>
  <div class="PriceSlider__inputs"><input name="input-min" class="FilterPriceInput PriceSlider__input_min" type="text" pattern="[0-9 ]*" autocomplete="off" value="21 990"><span class="PriceSlider__separator">—</span><input name="input-max" class="FilterPriceInput PriceSlider__input_max"
      type="text" pattern="[0-9 ]*" autocomplete="off" value="379 990"></div>
  <div class="FilterRange">
    <div class="rc-slider">
      <div class="rc-slider-rail"></div>
      <div class="rc-slider-track rc-slider-track-1" style="left: 0%; right: auto; width: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="rc-slider-step"></div>
      <div tabindex="0" class="rc-slider-handle rc-slider-handle-1" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow="0" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 0%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
      <div tabindex="0" class="rc-slider-handle rc-slider-handle-2" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow="99" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 100%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
      <div class="rc-slider-mark"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как получить концевые значения слайдера - значения ползунков?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Те, которые в коде равны 99 (aria-valuemax) ?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev я привел скриншот, в котором указаны крайние значения слайдера - 21990 - 379990

Comment: Скорее всего это не полный код слайдера, и есть ещё JavaScript для него, в котором эти значения прописаны или вычисляются.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var priceMin = $('.PriceSlider__input_min').val();
var priceMax = $('.PriceSlider__input_max').val();
  
console.log(priceMin);
console.log(priceMax);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="PriceSlider">
  <div class="PriceSlider__header">Цена, ₽</div>
  <div class="PriceSlider__inputs"><input name="input-min" class="FilterPriceInput PriceSlider__input_min" type="text" pattern="[0-9 ]*" autocomplete="off" value="21 990"><span class="PriceSlider__separator">—</span><input name="input-max" class="FilterPriceInput PriceSlider__input_max"
      type="text" pattern="[0-9 ]*" autocomplete="off" value="379 990"></div>
  <div class="FilterRange">
    <div class="rc-slider">
      <div class="rc-slider-rail"></div>
      <div class="rc-slider-track rc-slider-track-1" style="left: 0%; right: auto; width: 100%;"></div>
      <div class="rc-slider-step"></div>
      <div tabindex="0" class="rc-slider-handle rc-slider-handle-1" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow="0" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 0%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
      <div tabindex="0" class="rc-slider-handle rc-slider-handle-2" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="99" aria-valuenow="99" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 100%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);"></div>
      <div class="rc-slider-mark"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```